# Javascript prototype property shadowed

Tags: javascript, prototype, shadowing

I am a little confused with the Javascript prototyping mechanics. I have the following code :

```
function Person () {
  this.name = "no name";
  this.setName = function (n) {
    this.name = n;
  }
}

function Student () {
  this.id = "123";
}
Student.prototype = new Person();

s = new Student();
s.setName("Klaus");
```

After the execution of the code the object s has two names. The name "Klaus" in the object itself and the name "no name" in its prototype. I know that the property is shadowed and it works fine, but this doesn't feel naturally?! Is there a better way to only use the property of the prototype?

Comment: Why do you have the `this.setName = function (n) { this.name = n; }` construct at all?  Why don't you write `Person.prototype.setName = function (n) { this.name = n; }`  outside of your `Person()` function?

Comment: @Teemu as far as I understand it, `.setName` is called in the context of `s` though, which is the student. Thus the property would be on `s` as well (not in the prototype). Initially, when assigning `new Person` to the prototype property of `Student`, the property is created in its prototype as well.

Comment: Yes, but it seems OP understands this, they say: "I know that the [prototype] property is shadowed". The actual question is unclear though.

Comment: @Teemu oh yes you are right. I should stop writing answers for today.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Access `name` in the prototype and in the own property of `s` in context of `s`?

Comment: The property `name = "no name"` stays in the prototype and I can still retrieve it. Even if I'm doing it this way: `Person.prototype.setName = function (n) { this.name = n; }`.

Comment: Yes, but what is your question? What do you want instead own property shadowing the prototype property? The prototype is always shadowed if you set an own property using the same name. You've to refer directly to the prototype to get the original `name`, i.e. "no name".

Comment: You shouldn't change shadowed properties in the prototype in the first place, unless you have a really good reason to do so (it's not impossible, just a bit of work, since this is not the way JavaScript was designed to work). Just use instance properties, and different names if you need to keep an old value.

Comment: @nils Why not? Prototype properties are handy default values, excluding methods ofcourse.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't try to modify them though (which sounds like what he is trying to do). If you want to use them as default values, you can of course. But then you probably want to define them as properties on the `.prototype` property instead? Or do I have things backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work on the prototype property directly, but it would take a disproportionate amount of effort and is probably not considered best practice. Instead, you could call the `Person` constructor in the right `this` context.

First of all, it is highly recommended to use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead of the `new` Operator, when assigning to the `prototype` property of a function. With the `new` Operator, the `Person` constructor is called, but in the wrong `this` context. To prevent that, you can link them like this:

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

Instead, if you want to call the constructor of the prototypal Link (`Person`) inside Student, you could `call` it in the constructor with the correct `this` context:

```
function Student () {
  Person.call(this);
  this.id = "123";
}
```

Also, unless you want to create a single function for each instance, I would move the `setName` function to the `[[Prototype]]` of `Person`:

```
function Person () {
  this.name = "no name";
}

Person.prototype.setName = function (n) {
  this.name = n;
}

function Student () {
  Person.call(this); // Call the Person constructor
  this.id = "123";
}
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

s = new Student();
// s.name is 'no name'
s.setName("Klaus");
// s.name is 'Klaus'
```

Alternatively, as @Teemu mentioned, you could also place the `name` property on the `Person.prototype` to use it as a default value:

```
function Person () {
}

Person.prototype.setName = function (n) {
  this.name = n;
}

Person.prototype.name = "no name"; // Define the name directly

function Student () {
  Person.call(this); // you only need this, if there are other things happening in the Person constructor that you need as well
  this.id = "123";
}
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

s = new Student();
// s.name is 'no name'
s.setName("Klaus");
// s.name is 'Klaus'
```

Comment: If I do it this way the `name` is not longer in the prototype, but a property of the created object! That is what I wanted. It was just the `Object.create()` instead of `new`.